# Remove lines from a textfile?

Tags: python

I have a textfile.txt like this:

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
Fourth Line
Fifth Line
Sixth Line
```

How can I remove the first three lines and the last line most comfortable?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
with open('textfile.txt') as old, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as new:
    lines = old.readlines()
    new.writelines(lines[3:-1])
```

Answer (score 19):

This one doesn't use readlines() so it is ideal for bigger sized files.

```
numline=3 #3 lines to skip
p=""
o=open("output.txt","a")
f=open("file")
for i in range(numline):
    f.next()
for line in f:
    if p:
        o.write(p)
    p=line
f.close()
o.close()
```

Since there's a sed answer, here's an awk one

```
$ awk 'NR>=4{if(p)print p;p=$0;}' file
Fourth Line
Fifth Line
```

Answer (score 5):

```
data="".join(open("textfile.txt").readlines()[3:-1])
open("newfile.txt","wb").write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('file1.txt').readlines()

open('file1.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[4:])
```

This  code snippet will delete first four line from fie name "file1.txt"

Comment: should be f = open('file1.txt').readlines()

open('file1.txt', 'w').writelines(f[4:]) instead

Answer (score -4):

No Python solution but since your problem is a classic, I present you a sed solution.

```
$ sed -n -e "4,5p" textfile.txt
```

Of course the address `4,5` only works for exactly your input and required output :)