# delete all rows up to a specific row

Tags: python, python-3.x

How you can implement deleting lines in a text document up to a certain line?
I find the line number using the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
lookup = '00:00:00'
filename = "test.txt"
with open(filename) as text_file:
    for num, line in enumerate(text_file, 1):
        if lookup in line:
            print(num)
```

`print(num)` outputs me the value of the string, for example 66.
How do I delete all the lines up to 66, i.e. up to the found line by word?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove lines from a textfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064184/remove-lines-from-a-textfile)

Comment: Or [How to delete a specific line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/how-to-delete-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/how-to-delete-a-specific-line-in-a-file

Comment: @javadr If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a link as a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy.

```
filename = "test.txt"
lookup = '00:00:00'
with open(filename,'r') as text_file:
    lines = text_file.readlines()
res=[]
for i in range(0,len(lines),1):
    if lookup in lines[i]:
        res=lines[i:]
        break
with open(filename,'w') as text_file:
    text_file.writelines(res)
```

Comment: Why save lines to a list `res`? why not just write them directly to the file?

Comment: That should be fine too.

Comment: I tried your version, after which the file is empty

Comment: I just forgot to add lookup = '00:00:00'. It should work now.

Answer (score 3):

As proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4710090/6045800) with a small modification to your case:

- read all lines of the file.
- iterate the lines list until you reach the keyword.
- write all remaining lines

```py
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = iter(f.readlines())
with open("yourfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if lookup in line:
            f.write(line)
            break
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: Such a moment, in your solution, the found string is deleted, how to avoid it? Thanks.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Need to add a `break` after `f.write(line)` in the first loop. Otherwise, the first loop writes _only_ the lines which have the `lookup` term in it, and exhausts the iterator. With the `break`, once the first `line` is found and written, it then proceeds to the second loop which writes all the remaining lines.

Comment: @aneroid indeed! Good catch! It is a community wiki so you can feel free to fix it :) Did it anyway

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what lines you want to delete?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
lookup = '00:00:00'
filename = "test.txt" 
with open(filename) as text_file, open('okfile.txt', 'w') as ok: 
    lines = text_file.readlines()
    ok.writelines(lines[4:])
```

This will delete the first 4 lines and store them in a different document in case you wanna keep the original.

Remember to close the files when you're done with them :)

Answer (score 1):

Providing three alternate solutions. **All** begin with the same first part - reading:

```py
filename = "test.txt"
lookup = '00:00:00'
with open(filename) as text_file:
    lines = text_file.readlines()
```

The variations for the **second parts** are:

1. Using [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) which discards items from the iterator until the predicate (condition) returns `False` (ie discard while predicate is `True`). And from that point on, yields all the remaining items without re-checking the predicate:

   ```py
   import itertools

   with open(filename, 'w') as text_file:
       text_file.writelines(itertools.dropwhile(lambda line: lookup not in line, lines))
   ```

   Note that it says `not in`. So all the lines before `lookup` is found, are discarded.

   ***Bonus:*** If you wanted to do the opposite - write lines until you find the `lookup` and then stop, replace `itertools.dropwhile` with [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).
2. Using a flag-value (`found`) to determine when to start writing the file:

   ```py
   with open(filename, 'w') as text_file:
       found = False
       for line in lines:
           if not found and lookup in line:  # 2nd expression not checked once `found` is True
               found = True  # value remains True for all remaining iterations
           if found:
               text_file.write(line)
   ```
3. Similar to [@c yj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65886081/1431750), with some refinements - use enumerate instead of range, and then use the last index (`idx`) to write the lines from that point on; with no other intermediate variables needed:

   ```py
   for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
       if lookup in line:
           break
   with open(filename, 'w') as text_file:
       text_file.writelines(lines[idx:])
   ```